# Change color of specific pixels [Wand]

Tags: python, colors, wand

So, I'm using [Wand Python Library](http://wand-py.org) to mess around with some images.

I just want it to look at an image, pixel by pixel, and for each pixel that is a specific color, say '4d4d4d', replace that pixels color to something else, like '#00ff00'. That's it.
I've thoroughly scoured the documentation and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Comment: I don't speak Python at all, but you need to set the `fill` colour to `#00ff00` and then do a `draw.colour` with the paint method set to `replace` and you may need to add some `fuzz`... go to the documentation page covering `Drawing`, then scroll down to `Color & Matte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested the python code would be something like this:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

with Drawing() as draw:
    draw.fill_color = Color('#00ff00')
    draw.color(x,y,'replace')
    with Image(filename='image.jpg') as img:
        draw(img)
        img.save(filename='new_image.jpg')
```