# Replace a color using python Wand but coordinates unknown

Tags: python, replace, colors, imagemagick, wand

I am aware of [Replace a color using Wand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966455/replace-a-color-using-wand) and [Change color of specific pixels [Wand]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915785/change-color-of-specific-pixels-wand) but both of these use a line like

```
    draw.color(192,84,'replace')
```

In which you need to pass the location of a pixel of the relevant color. What if you know the color you want to replace but not its location? I want to replace the color of pixels in an image without passing a reference to the location of a pixel of that color. Do you really have to scan the entire image looking for something you already know is there?

The imagemagick equivalent would be

```
convert balloon.gif -fill white -opaque blue balloon_white.gif
```

Comment: You could try PythonMagick from the developers of ImageMagick.

Comment: I'll try and look at PythonMagick. [Seems you have to look to the C++ documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445985/where-can-i-find-pythonmagick-documentation) to understand it though. To tell the truth, I'm a little confused about what module to go with to manipulate images in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `-opaque` functionality, then you'll need to implement the `MagickOpaquePaintImage` C method.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.api import library
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.compat import nested

# Map C-API to Python
library.MagickOpaquePaintImage.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # Wand
                                           ctypes.c_void_p,  # target
                                           ctypes.c_void_p,  # fill
                                           ctypes.c_double,  # fuzz
                                           ctypes.c_bool)    # invert

with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    with nested(Color('#E93A43'), Color('ORANGE')) as (target, fill):
        library.MagickOpaquePaintImage(img.wand,
                                       target.resource,
                                       fill.resource,
                                       img.quantum_range * 0.10, # -fuzz 10%
                                       False)
    img.save(filename='output.png')
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Thanks @emcconville, that absolutely works. I'm curious to know what resources you used to craft that answer so that I might be able to do that for myself one day ;)

Comment: Happy to help. If this answered your original question, please mark this as "Accepted" so other readers know your problem was solved. As for resources to help understand: That's the beauty of OpenSource, there's nothing stoping you from reading the source code, and once you have a basic understanding of the authors intended design, all ported language bindings become perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since wand 0.5.4 the method `opaque_paint` is [available](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.opaque_paint) so the clever hack @emcconville proposed is not required anymore. You can do just:

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='rose:') as im:
  im.opaque_paint(target='#E93A43', fill='Orange', fuzz=0.10)
  im.save(filename='output.png')
```